# Entity Framework 4 Transaction Scope

Tags: entity-framework, transactions, scope

I am running 2 INSERTS inside a function. The first one is a non-entity framework INSERT (AD0.NET). The second one is an EntityContext.SaveChanges()

Can I not nest both of these inside a Transaction Scope ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{

   InsertRecord();

   context.SaveChanges();

   scope.Complete();
}
```

Comment: @Kvlive can give more details?

Answer (score 0):

As Eranga says it is perfectly feasible, if somewhat messy.

See [this link for peace of mind on TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx)

Also consider setting the isolationlevel for the transaction scope e.g.

```
TransactionOptions options = new TransactionOptions();
options.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Serializable;

using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, options))
{
// Do something here
}
```

Two different database inserts (two different concurrent connections) will cause transactionscope to escalate to a distributed transaction. Use [DTCPIng.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2868) to test it will work between the machines in questions.

P.S. Different databases have thier own default isolation levels, so it's best practice to specify this in your code, e.g. SQL Server Express uses Serializable by default, SQL Server (Full Version) does not!